# Extensive memory usage when uploading assets (images, videos) to firebase in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Suppose I have an array of `UIImage` called `photos`, they are to be uploaded to Firebase storage. I wish to do the following things:

1. Upload them to Firebase storage
2. Get paths of the uploaded photos and store in an array called `uploadedAssets` (**paths**, not download url, it looks like this: "photos/folder_name/photo_id"), where "folder_name" is randomly generated and "photo_id" is an integer, representing the order of photos
3. Call Cloud Function and pass `uploadedAssets` to it. The server then uses the paths to find all pictures and generates a thumbnail for each one.
4. Finally, store the original photos' download urls and thumbnails' download urls in database.

I have something that's working, but uses too much memory (300+MB when uploading only 4 pictures):

```
// Swift
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.init(label: "AssetQueue")

var uploadedAssets = [String]()
let folderName: String = UUID().uuidString

dispatchQueue.async {
    for i in 0..<photos.count {
        dispatchGroup.enter()

        let photo: UIImage = photos[i]
        let fileName: String = "\(folderName)/\(i)"
        let assetRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("photos/\(fileName)")
        let metaData = StorageMetaData()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

        if let dataToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 0.75) {
            assetRef.putData(
                dataToUpload,
                metaData: metaData,
                completion: { (_, error) in
                    uploadedAssets.append("photos/\(fileName)")
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: dispatchQueue) {
    Alamofire.request(
        "https://<some_url>",
        method: .post,
        parameters: [
            "uploadedAssets": uploadedAssets
        ]
    )
}
```

And the code that generates thumbnails runs on server side, therefore, in my opinion, is irrelevant, I won't post it here. So, the above code snippet consumes 300+MB of memory when there are 4 photos to upload. After successfully uploaded those photos, the memory usage **stays** at 300+MB and never drops. When I try to upload more, say another 4 photos, it could even go up to 450+MB. I know that's not normal, but can't seem to figure out why this would happen?